# How to extract just the date portion from a time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following piece of code currently in my view.

**display.html.erb**

```
<% @total_sales_volume.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.transaction_date %>
<% end %>
```

What gets displayed currently: `2016-02-23 00:00:00 UTC`

What I want to display: `2016-02-23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the following:

```
<% @total_sales_volume.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.transaction_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @total_sales_volume.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.transaction_date.to_date %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the strftime function as follows:

```
<% @total_sales_volume.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.transaction_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
<% end %>
```

These are the useful formats which you can specify in the strftime function:

```
Date (Year, Month, Day):
  %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
          -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
  %C - year / 100 (round down.  20 in 2009)
  %y - year % 100 (00..99)

  %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
          %_m  blank-padded ( 1..12)
          %-m  no-padded (1..12)
  %B - The full month name (``January'')
          %^B  uppercased (``JANUARY'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
          %^b  uppercased (``JAN'')
  %h - Equivalent to %b

  %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
          %-d  no-padded (1..31)
  %e - Day of the month, blank-padded ( 1..31)

  %j - Day of the year (001..366)

Time (Hour, Minute, Second, Subsecond):
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
  %k - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, blank-padded ( 0..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (01..12)
  %l - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, blank-padded ( 1..12)
  %P - Meridian indicator, lowercase (``am'' or ``pm'')
  %p - Meridian indicator, uppercase (``AM'' or ``PM'')

  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

  %S - Second of the minute (00..59)

  %L - Millisecond of the second (000..999)
  %N - Fractional seconds digits, default is 9 digits (nanosecond)
          %3N  millisecond (3 digits)
          %6N  microsecond (6 digits)
          %9N  nanosecond (9 digits)
          %12N picosecond (12 digits)
```

Comment: Thats a syntax error - you need to wrap the format string in quotes

Answer (score 0):

You would use [`.strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime). The weird name is from the ancient C function which it emulates.

```
<% @total_sales_volume.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.transaction_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
<% end %>
```